# Memory management of returned structs using ARC in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, struct, memory-management, heap-memory, automatic-ref-counting

Am I supposed to explicitly free memory when I get a struct returned from a function such as NSMakeRange() when using ARC in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You couldn't even do that either. It's not an object, it's not something allocated using `malloc()`, nothing like that. It's a primitive value that gets copied whenever necessary and vanishes when its scope ends.

> when using ARC in Objective-C?

Yes. And when not using it. It doesn't matter - ARC and MRC are concerned with Objective-C objects only. Not with those with automatic storage duration, not with those allocated by the C standard library functions.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the answer doesn't change between MRR and ARC, although I know the latter is a dirty word for you.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair enough, added the "disclaimer" :)